# IBM SBT Connections - SearchUtils Class

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

While trying to Search using IBM SBT, I was getting a 404 error.
The Url tha got generated by the SearchService class is

https://Connections-Server/search/basic/atom/search?query=&constraint=%7B%22type%22%3A%22category%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%22Tag%2Fdubh%22%5D%2C%22exactMatch%22%3A%22false%22%7D

Looking upon this, the word basic in the path seems to be the issue.
I looked at the SearchUtils.class to find that it contains

Comment: is this the IBM Connections Cloud?

Comment: @Paul any idea about how this can be handled ?

Comment: someone on my team will be looking at this.

Comment: what version of the SBT do you have and what method id you call?  the SearchUrls class shouldn't return what you had above.

Comment: @Paul I am using version sbtsdk-1.0.3.20140723-1200. And was trying to call the following function.                                                          SearchService svc = new SearchService();
ResultList results = svc.getResultsByTag("policies");

Comment: please use the latest 1.1.3 branch as I believe it's fixed there.

Comment: How can I do that ? Do I need to build that ? Please advise

Comment: https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/releases <- it's released